# How can I select columns with specific collation from mysql?

Tags: mysql, collation

I wondering how can I select columns with specific collation.

For example, **I want to select all the columns which their collation is utf-8.**

How can I get these things done?

Thanks very much!

Comment: From all tables or from a specific table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SHOW FULL COLUMNS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html) is what you need:

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM xxx WHERE COLLATION = 'utf8_general_ci'
```